# fetching data from firebase without using primary key of the table

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve posts posted by currently loggedin user. But with current code all the posts are getting retrieved. How to retrieve expected data by using the uid from customer table?

`post_id` is primary key of Customer table not `customerid(uid)`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please add your images inside your question (don't use links) in order to help others understand your issue.

Comment: So you want to get all customers with a specific uid? Please respond with @.

Comment: "with current code all the posts are getting retrieved" Please share the current code in your question, so that we can see what you're doing. Posting the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is by far the best way to get help quickly here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i just want to access specific complaint place by user by their uid...so i can place list of complaint place by specific user in there "my complaint module".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a reference of the current user and use it to query post posted by the user like this:

```
FirebaseUser user =FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); 
Query reference;

                       reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
                       getReference("customers").orderByChild("customerId").equalTo(user.getUid());


                       reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
                       ValueEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                       String 
                         customerId =datas.child("customerId").getValue().toString();

                       String 
                         customerName =datas.child("customerName").getValue().toString();

                       String 
                         phone =datas.child("phone").getValue().toString();


                      }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                  });

    }
```

Comment: I just want to access complaint place by user..i don't all post being retrieved..only retrieve the complaint details on based on their customerid thats a uid....so i can add list of complaints place by specific user(as per uid) in my app "my complaint" module

Comment: Can you do what frank told you to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this ,

Step 1. Get the right child node , and query on it  by getting the current logded user uid:-

```
  String currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

  DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("customers").orderByChild("customerId").equalTo(currentLoginId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            List<Customers> customers = new ArrayList<>();
            while (dataSnapshots.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshots.next();
                Customers user = dataSnapshotChild.getValue(Customer.class);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: How can get 'currentLoginId' ?

Comment: Oh my mistake, currentUser variable is the currentloginUid , please use it.